# Was Shmi Skywalker's death ordered by Darth Sidious?

Tags: star-wars

The death of Anakin's mother, [Shmi Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shmi_Skywalker_Lars), conducted him to his first steps on the path to the Dark Side of the Force. In an act of anger and vengeance, Anakin slew everyone in the Tusken camp.

This event is a milestone in Anakin's fall, and we know Anakin is a crucial part of Darth Sidious's [Grand Plan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Plan). So, is Shmi's abduction, torturing and death part of the plan? Did Sidious order, suggest, or cause those event in any way? Or, to the contrary, did he not even foresee them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reviewing all the relevant Wikis/Wikias (Tatooine, Vader, Anakin, Palpatine, Tusken), I didn't find any canon information confirming that theory.

However, neither have I found any info that disproves it.

I read "Tatooine Ghost" and it doesn't mention anything there either (one likely source)

Comment: It was surely on Sidious' TODO list, but it may have just been a lucky turn of events.

Comment: Tatooine Ghost deals with incidents taking place after the death of Vader. Nothing in there references a Sidious/Tusken connection

Comment: Sidious is the most powerful Dark Sider in the Galaxy. Many events that are not under his direct control will still tend towards results that will favor him. As Ben Kenobi said in A New Hope "In my experience, there's no such thing as luck"

Answer (score 16):

Palpatine was Anakin's advisor long before Shmi's death.  Palpy was the first to congratulate Anakin on his first real  assignment protecting Padme.  Even prior to that, he suggested detailing Obi-Wan and Anakin to Padme, knowing full well the emotions it would stir within Anakin.  He was already pulling the strings in preparation to  placing Anakin on the path of the Sith.  It's not outside the realm of possibility that Palpatine orchestrated Shmi's death, although there's no proof of it.

Answer (score 5):

"That act took place before Anakin really entered Palpatine's radar."

Actually no since at the end of "*The Phantom Menace*" before the celebration, the just named chancellor Palpatine says to Anakin that he will follow his career closely.

Also in the first draft of REVENGE OF THE SITH, when Palpatine tries to lure Anakin into the dark side and the young jedi finds out that Palpatine is actually a Sith Lord... Palpatine tells him that he was the one who orchestrated the death of his mom.

In that same script, there is no mention of Darth Plagueis but Palpatine tells Anakin that he fathered him through midi-chlorians in his mom. Something that was taken out of the final film.

Comment: This answer would be better if you could cite or link to some sources.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this site.

Comment: Actually the first paragraph is directly taken from THE PHANTOM MENACE film.

As for the first draft of REVENGE OF THE SITH, this part of the script has been well documented. You can actually read about it in the Secret History of Star Wars book.

Comment: Those are words of a politian.  They ring hollow while foreshadowing in the corny way the first movie was full of.  And yest that was in the first draft script for 3 but Lucas nixed it and forced a revision. So this is NON Canon as it was rejected.

Comment: Sorry but Palpatine clearly mentions this to Anakin at the end of THE PHANTOM MENACE. It has nothing to do with the supposedly corny way (your opinion actually) of the first movie.

Since it was not in the final script it doesn't mean it is non canon! It more "loyal" to the film's story and characters then all of the expended universe mumbo jumbo.

Comment: So then regarding THE LORD OF THE RINGS, you would consider the Silmarillion non canon before it was published, even though all of its writing was used as backstory for the books Tolkien actually wrote and got published?

Comment: Then you would probably say the exact same thing for the Journal of the Whills, which George Lucas wrote when he started to work on STAR WARS in 1973? Yet lots of elements from it actually ended up in films... some even just in the prequel. Would those be non canon because it was never published but was actually the flesh and bone of the characters and story we known?

Comment: @Arc-Vile Sorry, A draft script is N-Canon : From http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon : "N is Non-Canon. What-if stories (such as stories published under the Infinities label) and **anything else directly and irreconcilably contradicted by higher canon ends up here**. N is the only level that is not considered canon by Lucasfilm. Information cut from canon, deleted scenes, **or from canceled Star Wars works falls into this category** as well, unless another canonical work references it and it is declared canon."

Comment: Those scenes are mentioned in Darth Plageous but Anakin was not part of his plans for the future at the time.

Answer (score -1):

It seems pretty obvious that Palpatine arranged this just from circumstantial evidence. What benefit to the Tuscans did torturing Shmi provide? Further, influencing people by torturing their loved ones is typical Sith tactic, as we see in The Empire Strikes Back with Vader torturing Han ("they didn't even ask me any questions.") So while not stated, it's so strongly implied as to be likely.

Comment: No.  It does not seem obvious.

Answer (score -4):

That act took place before Anakin really entered Palpatine's radar.  It was on his return from this adventure that the Chancellor (he wasn't even emperor yet) first took a significant interest in Skywalker.  I suspect that it was at that point that Palpatine noticed the potential for full conversion to the dark side that now existed in the young Jedi.  Had Obi Wan been there to reign in his apprentices rage then Sideous would have gone forward with his current apprentice.

Comment: I think you're forgetting the last scene in the Phantom Menace.  I think the phrase Palpatine used was "great interest".  Sounds like a radar signature to me.

Comment: @RexKerr - It sounds like hollow words of a politician combined with the corny foreshadowing that the first movie was full of.  It was after he returned that the Chancellor began to bring Anakin in for his counsel.

Comment: @chad from [Star Wars: Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Plagueis) novel plot resume : "such as seeking Dooku as a placeholder Sith apprentice and ally in the war. But the biggest part in Darth Sidious's plan is young Anakin Skywalker"

Comment: When started reading the bounty hunter series this book was not available.  I am just about to finish it (planned as the new FoJ book is out next week)  But I will push this one in front of it.  I may agree after I read it...

Comment: @DavRob60 - That book confirms my thoughts that Anakin was not really part of Palpatines plans when she died.  He did notice that Anakin had hatred in his heart and that the jedi tactics would push him towards the dark side.  But Dooku was his plan until he could find the appropriate apprentice.